# How to setup caching rules in google cdn

Tags: html, caching, cdn

I want to cache the whole page including the html to Google CDN. Can you tell me how to proceed with it, what are the caching rules that i have to write. Also, i want google CDN not to cache the wp-admin folder of my site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read our [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Comment: Unless it's changed, Google CDN requires you to use Google load balancer or cloud storage origins. Just making sure that's where your content is stored.